# How to use nested snippets in VS Code (with Latex)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nested, latex, substring, vscode-snippets

For some reason, I can't use nested snippets when I'm writing the first one, VS code doesn't understand that I want to use another until I've reached the end of the first one.

## Example:

### Fragment from latex.json

```
"Limit": {
        "prefix": "lim",
        "body": [
            "\\lim_{${1:x}\\to${2:\\infty}} $3 $0"
        ]
    },
    "Union": {
        "prefix": "union",
        "body": [
            "\\bigcup_{${1:i}=${2:0}}^{${3:\\infty}} $4 $0"
        ]
    },
```

### Fragment from article.json

```
$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \bigcup_{i=0}^{x} A_i  $
```

In fact, writing "union" at the moment the cursor is in $3 from the limit does nothing because IntelliSense is waiting for the limit to reach $0. Therefore, I think it should be a way of ignoring the characters before the expression, for example, when you are using AutoHotKey hotstrings and you can write "?" so it will be triggered even when it is inside another word.

Comment: what if you press `Ctrl+Space` after `union`, or press `Esc` to terminate the current snippet, what is the purpose of `$3` before `$0`, they both are at the end of the snippet

Comment: Thank you so much @rioV8, Ctrl+Space works for me without terminating the current snippet. Actually I don't have that $3 in my snippets, but I thought it will be easier to understand than if I use set inclusions as union subscripts, for example.